# Image button displayed as tile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert an image through css of a button but for some reason it gets displayed as tile image. Why is this happening and how do I fix it to make it as a single image?

```html
<button id="myImg" type="button" style="
    background:url(https://picsum.photos/200);
    position: fixed; 
    z-index:11; 
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    display: block; 
    ">
```

Comment: I got it, it was due to background repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will not completely solve using `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

You just need to add `background-size: cover;` so that the image cover your full button space.

Thanks me later.

```html
<button id="myImg" type="button" style="
    background:url(https://picsum.photos/200);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 70%;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index:11; 
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    display: block; 
    ">
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not know this was the thing with css that we must add a background no repeat after adding an image.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Accept your own answer so that discussion is closed

Comment: Only in 2 days I can do that